# Grails 3.1.9, Quartz and Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, grails, quartz-scheduler

I am trying to implement quartz plugin with clustered setting in my application, which is build on Grails 3.1.9, I am using Postgresql DB. Here are my config for quartz

```
quartz.pluginEnabled: true
quartz.jdbcStore: true
quartz.isClustered: true
quartz.autoStartup: false
quartz.waitForJobsToCompleteOnShutdown: true
quartz.scheduler.instanceName: "JobInstanceName"
quartz.purgeQuartzTablesOnStartup: false
quartz.threadPool.class: org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
quartz.threadPool.threadCount: 10
quartz.threadPool.threadPriority: 5
quartz.jobStore.class: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold: 60000
quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate
quartz.jobStore.dataSource: 'quartzDB'
quartz.jobStore.isClustered: true
quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix: qrtz_
quartz.jobStore.useProperties: false
quartz.dataSource: 'quartzDB'
quartz.dataSource.quartzDB.driverClassName: "org.postgresql.Driver"
quartz.dataSource.quartzDB.driver: org.postgresql.Driver
quartz.dataSource.quartzDB.URL: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/quartz_database
quartz.dataSource.quartzDB.user: username
quartz.dataSource.quartzDB.password: password
```

But I am getting these errors; the strange thing is, the exception seems to be coming from org.h2.command...

```
    ERROR org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore - ClusterManager: Error managing cluster: Failure obtaining db row lock: Table "QRTZ_LOCKS" not found; SQL statement:
SELECT * FROM qrtz_LOCKS WHERE SCHED_NAME = 'QuartzJobCheAu' AND LOCK_NAME = ? FOR UPDATE [42102-191]
org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.LockException: Failure obtaining db row lock: Table "QRTZ_LOCKS" not found; SQL statement:
SELECT * FROM qrtz_LOCKS WHERE SCHED_NAME = 'QuartzJobCheAu' AND LOCK_NAME = ? FOR UPDATE [42102-191]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdRowLockSemaphore.executeSQL(StdRowLockSemaphore.java:157)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.DBSemaphore.obtainLock(DBSemaphore.java:113)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.doCheckin(JobStoreSupport.java:3258)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$ClusterManager.manage(JobStoreSupport.java:3858)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$ClusterManager.run(JobStoreSupport.java:3895)
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "QRTZ_LOCKS" not found; SQL statement:
SELECT * FROM qrtz_LOCKS WHERE SCHED_NAME = 'QuartzJobCheAu' AND LOCK_NAME = ? FOR UPDATE [42102-191]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:5349)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableFilter(Parser.java:1245)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimpleFromPart(Parser.java:1884)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimple(Parser.java:2032)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSub(Parser.java:1878)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectUnion(Parser.java:1699)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelect(Parser.java:1687)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:443)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:315)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:287)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:252)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:560)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:501)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1188)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:73)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:276)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor182.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1426)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:126)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:81)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy59.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor182.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1426)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy$LazyConnectionInvocationHandler.invoke(LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.java:376)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy60.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor182.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1426)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy$TransactionAwareInvocationHandler.invoke(TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy.java:240)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy60.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor182.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1426)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.AttributeRestoringConnectionInvocationHandler.invoke(AttributeRestoringConnectionInvocationHandler.java:73)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy93.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdRowLockSemaphore.executeSQL(StdRowLockSemaphore.java:88)
    ... 4 common frames omitted
ERROR org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore - ClusterManager: Error managing cluster: Failure obtaining db row lock: Table "QRTZ_LOCKS" not found; SQL statement:
SELECT * FROM qrtz_LOCKS WHERE SCHED_NAME = 'QuartzJobCheAu' AND LOCK_NAME = ? FOR UPDATE [42102-191]
org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.LockException: Failure obtaining db row lock: Table "QRTZ_LOCKS" not found; SQL statement:
SELECT * FROM qrtz_LOCKS WHERE SCHED_NAME = 'QuartzJobCheAu' AND LOCK_NAME = ? FOR UPDATE [42102-191]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdRowLockSemaphore.executeSQL(StdRowLockSemaphore.java:157)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.DBSemaphore.obtainLock(DBSemaphore.java:113)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.doCheckin(JobStoreSupport.java:3258)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$ClusterManager.manage(JobStoreSupport.java:3858)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$ClusterManager.run(JobStoreSupport.java:3895)
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "QRTZ_LOCKS" not found; SQL statement:
SELECT * FROM qrtz_LOCKS WHERE SCHED_NAME = 'QuartzJobCheAu' AND LOCK_NAME = ? FOR UPDATE [42102-191]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:5349)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableFilter(Parser.java:1245)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimpleFromPart(Parser.java:1884)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimple(Parser.java:2032)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSub(Parser.java:1878)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectUnion(Parser.java:1699)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelect(Parser.java:1687)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:443)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:315)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:287)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:252)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:560)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:501)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1188)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:73)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:276)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor182.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1426)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:126)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:81)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy59.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor182.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1426)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy$LazyConnectionInvocationHandler.invoke(LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.java:376)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy60.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor182.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1426)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy$TransactionAwareInvocationHandler.invoke(TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy.java:240)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy60.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor182.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1426)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.AttributeRestoringConnectionInvocationHandler.invoke(AttributeRestoringConnectionInvocationHandler.java:73)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy93.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdRowLockSemaphore.executeSQL(StdRowLockSemaphore.java:88)
    ... 4 common frames omitted
ERROR org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore - MisfireHandler: Error handling misfires: Database error recovering from misfires.
org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Database error recovering from misfires.
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.doRecoverMisfires(JobStoreSupport.java:3197)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$MisfireHandler.manage(JobStoreSupport.java:3935)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$MisfireHandler.run(JobStoreSupport.java:3956)
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "QRTZ_TRIGGERS" not found; SQL statement:
SELECT COUNT(TRIGGER_NAME) FROM qrtz_TRIGGERS WHERE SCHED_NAME = 'QuartzJobCheAu' AND NOT (MISFIRE_INSTR = -1) AND NEXT_FIRE_TIME < ? AND TRIGGER_STATE = ? [42102-191]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:5349)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableFilter(Parser.java:1245)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimpleFromPart(Parser.java:1884)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimple(Parser.java:2032)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSub(Parser.java:1878)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectUnion(Parser.java:1699)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelect(Parser.java:1687)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:443)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:315)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:287)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:252)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:560)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:501)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1188)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:73)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:276)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor182.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1426)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:126)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:81)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy59.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor182.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1426)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy$LazyConnectionInvocationHandler.invoke(LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.java:376)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy60.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor182.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1426)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy$TransactionAwareInvocationHandler.invoke(TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy.java:240)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy60.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor182.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1426)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.AttributeRestoringConnectionInvocationHandler.invoke(AttributeRestoringConnectionInvocationHandler.java:73)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy93.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate.countMisfiredTriggersInState(StdJDBCDelegate.java:390)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.doRecoverMisfires(JobStoreSupport.java:3176)
    ... 2 common frames omitted
```

I have created all the tables needed in postgresql DB, nothing has been written to the DB. I am not sure why the exception occurs from org.h2. Any ideas?

I am using org.grails.plugins:quartz:2.0.1

Comment: You're not showing the full stacktrace, that query is a standard Quartz query. You said you created all of the tables needed but did that include QRTZ_LOCKS? If so you might be connecting to a different database

Comment: I can see the QRTZ_LOCKS table in my database, the full stacktrace consist of similar error saying that other tables are missing as well. I am confused as how could the plugin connect to different DB since i clearly have specified the DB.

Comment: What's the name and the full path of the quartz configuration file?

Comment: All the configurations are in application.yml file, it looks like quartz is completely ignoring dataSource properties.

Comment: org.h2... suggests the DB being hit is an H2 DB.

Comment: Yes. It seems like quartz is looking for the tables in h2 db and ignoring datasource configurations.